# proofreadiing a paper on Descartes. Need help on line "a true physics..."

Tags: descartes, physics

I'm copy editing a paper on Descartes written by an Italian in French and then translated into English. I need some help with a phrase she uses: "... a true physics..." I have no background in philosophy or physics. Does that phrase make sense? Does it work? Thanks.

Comment: Please get us the whole sentence and some context; in anyone of these languages.

Comment: Without any sort of context this question has nothing to do with philosophy. If you want someone to help you evaluate the philosophical content of the paper and whether or not that phrase is relevant, at the very least you would need to supply us with the full context of the phrase (hopefully in more than one of the languages) but still that is only borderline a question about philosophy and I have a feeling it will probably be closed as being off topic. But the first step towards making this a fuller answer is, as Jo says, giving the full context of the phrase.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My job isn't to assess the merits of the paper's content, or even understand it, really, but to improve the paper's readability. The (not yet corrected) sentence runs "...Descartes affirms that only a necessary physics can resist and respond to the objections put forward by skeptics ..." My languge question is whether it's common usage among you all to use "physics" as a countable noun (a physics). That's all I need to know - is "a physics" common usage? Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: @fixer I consider the term "a necessary physics" correct.

Comment: This looks like it belongs on [English Language & Usage.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: 'A necessary physics' doesn't ring true to my English ear. I can't find many adjectives that Descartes applies to physics. He certainly thought in terms of mathematical, sometimes specifically geometrical, physics. Why not ask the author what text(s) s/he has in mind ? It's a reasonable request.

Comment: I don't think this *is* a problem for the English language site. It's not that we philosophers are too inarticulate to find the right English phrase : the author's meaning is the trouble. For it precisely is not clear what the author means; until that has been settled, we have no way of knowing what the right or a suitable English phrase, adjective or whatever would be.

Comment: You might try to locate this book in the reference section of a library. https://www.amazon.com/Dictionary-Untranslatables-Philosophical-Translation-Transnation/dp/0691138702 I differ from those above who think this belongs at English language and usage. Your intuition is good. The book I link to here may not help you in this case, I'm not sure, but I wanted you to know about this great resource.  Good luck.

Comment: Just in case the link gets broken, Dictionary of Untranslatables: a Philosophical Lexicon, Barbara Cassin, Ed.